# Complete sort -u option command for a specifically removal purpose

Tags: sort

How is a complete `sort -u` option command syntax for a specifically removal purpose removing any not 100% exact duplicate lines that is instead of finding exact characters in line, every line with existing space between words its length may vary so that is considered duplicate of which to remove?

Comment: Are the number of spaces between words in the final output relevant? Do the lines that are produced at the end need to be actual lines from the data, or could they have had their spaces altered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
perl -ae 'print unless $seen{"@F"}++' < file
```

Would not print a line if its `F`ields (`@F` in `a`wk mode), joined with spaces¹ have been seen before. Pipe to `sort` if you also want that output to be sorted.

Fields in that case are separated by ASCII whitespace characters (space, horizontab tab, newline, carriage return, form feed and since 5.18 vertical tab, same as matched by POSIX `isspace()` in the C locale).

---

<sup>¹ The elements of `@list` inside double quotes are joined using the value of the `$"` special variable which by default is a single space, so `"@F"` is like `join(" ", @F)`.</sup>

Comment: Any further knowledge on possibility that the operand is regex instead of string (in @F or $_)

Answer (score 0):

`sort` itself can't do what you want. Your specification is a bit vague, but the general method is that you'd normalize your input (e.g., remove all whitespace at end and beginning of each line, replace multiple consecutive spaces with a single one using `tr --squeeze-repeats ' ' ' '`), then sort the result.

The usual piping operations make that easy; you could merge all this in a single `sed` command, but assuming your data isn't large (in computer terms) anyways, as you're applying `sort` to it:

```bash
input_command | sed 's/^ *//' | sed 's/ *$//' | tr --squeeze-repeats ' ' ' ' | sort -u
```

Note that the output you're getting doesn't necessarily correspond to actual lines of input – for example,

```
 d c b a
a  b c d
a b  c d
```

was your input, then the output would be

```
a b c d
d c b a
```

both of which lines don't exist *exactly*  in the input, but they're representatives from the same equivalent classes as lines from the input.

If you need to reproduce actual input lines, shell programming probably takes you only half as far as four lines of python, or another language with associative arrays (`dict` in Python) would take you.

As a matter of fact, Python's `dict` isn't even an elegant choice here, as you can't specify the iteration order, Python 3.7+ guarantees it to be insertion order, which is just terrible; `dict` is just conveniently available.

C++'s `std::set<std::string, [](const auto &a , const auto& b){ return normalize(a) > normalize(b); }> unique_lines;` type with your own normalization `normalize` function would be better, because you could in the end just

```
std::set<std::string,
         [](const auto &a, const auto &b) {
           return normalize(a) > normalize(b);
         }>
    lineset;
std::ifstream in_file("yourinputfile.txt");
std::copy(std::istream_iterator<std::string>(in_file),
          std::istream_iterator<std::string>(),
          std::inserter(lineset, lineset.end()));
for (const auto &unified_line : lineset)
  std::cout << std::format("{}\n", unified_line);
```

Comment: Or more portably and likely more efficiently and considering all spacing characters: `sed 's/[[:space:]]\{1,\}/ /g; s/^ //; s/ $//'`. See `tr -s ' '` as the standard equivalent of your GNU `tr --squeeze-repeats ' ' ' '`

Comment: absolutely! But I avoid using multi-command `sed` programs in answers, because, well, it's easier to see what each part of a pipe does individually, but you're right, that's significantly better.